# html table with rowspan border issue in Firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, border

I've checked few topics about tables, FireFox and border issues, but still searching for an answer.
I've got a simple table with `rowspan` and `bootstrap` but on some rows horizontal border is extended to next after rowspan column. Is there any workaround for FireFox?

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Lorem</th>
          <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</th>
          <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">3</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>dolor sit amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">3</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>dolor sit amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">3</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>dolor sit amet</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here an example http://codepen.io/AlexanderStepchkov/pen/vNyzez
Check it in Firefox and other browser (I've tried in IE11 and Chrome)

Comment: i tried it in chrome, ff and ie and it looks the same in all 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I could find is; the issue is due to

> border-collapse: collapse

property on table.

Try `table { border-collapse: separate !important;}`

Checkout this codepen aswell http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avBgXN

Hope this helps